# How does minimizing the rank of a matrix help us impute missing values in it?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, sparse-matrices, nuclear-norm, matrix-completion

I am not really a math guru myself, but I know that many estimation or approximation problems can be reformulated as minimizing the rank of a matrix. Although that is really hard, we can try to minimize the nuclear norm instead, which turns out to be a convex optimization problem that is easier to solve.

Let's say I have a sparse matrix **X** which I need to fill and somehow I've found the minimal nuclear norm. How can I impute the missing values now? And how the whole idea of minimizing the rank relate to that? Can you provide me with a simple(visual, if possible) example, please?

Comment: If you know that the matrix has low rank that puts more constraints on how the entries relate to each other. As a simple example, if you know that two rows must sum up to a third row, that implies a bunch of linear equations between the entries in those rows that fill in some of the entries if you know the others.